# How to make a pop up appear when you click a button in html

Tags: html, popup

I need help with this and because I've been researching the internet and I found nothing good, so I'm trying to make a pop up when a user clicks a button. This is the code I found but did not work:

```
$('#show').on('click', function () {
    $('.center').show();
    $(this).hide();
})

$('#close').on('click', function () {
    $('.center').hide();
    $('#show').show();
})

.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.hideform {
    display: none;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center hideform">
    <button id="close" style="float: right;">X</button>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<button id="show">Show form</button>
```

And since [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) lets you test the code, I did and it worked but when I tested it on my website it did not work. Here is the website [enter link description here](http://flounder.epizy.com/tests/test-popup.html). Help is appreciated!

Comment: My guess..... attaching event before element exists

Comment: The website you provided requires authentication.

Comment: He may or may not have meant requiring a user name and a password (authentication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript code should be wrapped with the `<script>` tag. CSS code should be wrapped with the `<style>` tag inside the `<head>` tag (although not mandatory).

The HTML you should be using is this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.hideform {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center hideform">
    <button id="close" style="float: right;">X</button>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<button id="show">Show form</button>
<script>
$('#show').on('click', function () {
    $('.center').show();
    $(this).hide();
})

$('#close').on('click', function () {
    $('.center').hide();
    $('#show').show();
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @YT_Xaos I find it difficult to help when your website requires me to authenticate. This is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/qYUMzFj.png

Comment: @YT_Xaos I checked the site. What's the problem? I see the form.