# pop-up using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages

I am working on a portfolio website, for a product management and cloud profile, I am using a template as I am not a programmer:
https://github.com/codewithsadee/vcard-personal-portfolio
This is the portfolio I am using and this is my GitHub repo, with all my changes:
https://github.com/pranaysparihar/portfolio

In the 'Portfolio' section of my website, for every project, I want to open a pop-up window with the details of the project, but I am not able to work out how to code it, I am sure a modal should do the trick, it is a public repository so anyone around the globe should be able to take a look and hopefully contribute, would be great if someone could help me out here.

This is the current snippet:

```
    <li class="project-item  active" data-filter-item data-category="cloud projects">
      <a href="https://google.com">

        <figure class="project-img">
          <div class="project-item-icon-box">
            <ion-icon name="eye-outline"></ion-icon>
          </div>

          <img src="./assets/images/project-9.png" alt="arrival" loading="lazy">
        </figure>

        <h3 class="project-title">Arrival</h3>

        <p class="project-category">Cloud Projects</p>

      </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a pop up appear when you click a button in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134637/how-to-make-a-pop-up-appear-when-you-click-a-button-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a CSS stylesheet for a modal. The modal will always be in the middle due to "fixed" position. Furthermore I have added a onclick event on your a tags, to trigger the javascript function openModal and the new modal divs below your  tag. You have to enter your data there, but at least you have an idea on how it can work. Finally see the script.js modifications on how the modal works.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

[image: Modal]

CSS:

```
/*-----------------------------------*\
  #MODAL
\*-----------------------------------*/

.modal {
  display: none;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid var(--jet);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--eerie-black-2);
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 16px;
  color: var(--white-2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}

.show-modal {
  display: block;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: var(--white-2);
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: var(--light-gray-70);
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*-----------------------------------*\
  #RESPONSIVE
\*-----------------------------------*/
```

index.html

```
  <body>
    <!-- modals-->
    <div class="modal project-1">
      <span class="close" onclick="closeAllOpenModals()">&times;</span>
      <div class="content">Here is my modal text 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal project-2">
      <span class="close" onclick="closeAllOpenModals()">&times;</span>
      <div class="content">Here is my modal text 2</div>
    </div>

    <!--
    - #MAIN
  -->

    <main>
      <!--
      - #SIDEBAR
    -->
```

Add onclick events to all your a tags within your projects

```
<a href="#" onclick="openModal('project-1')">
```

script.js - Paste it on the bottom of your file

```
function closeAllOpenModals() {
  let modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
  if (modals) {
    for (let i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
      let modal = modals[i];
      modal.classList.remove("show-modal");
    }
  }
}

//open modal
function openModal(project) {
  //close all modals before
  closeAllOpenModals();

  let modalName = `.modal.${project}`;
  //get modal
  let modal = document.querySelector(modalName);
  //check if modal is set
  if (modal) {
    //show modal
    modal.classList.add("show-modal");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot it is working now, is there anyway to make it responsive based on the screen size ? Thanks.

Comment: you can change the min-height and min-width to a percentage value like 35% or 30%